# Why is an encrypted cookie set in middleware also returning string length?

Tags: php, laravel

I am following [this tutorial](https://jameswmontgomery.com/2017/12/17/how-to-add-referral-tracking-system-with-laravel/), as part of which you set a cookie from the middleware.

Because my custom middleware where the cookie is set comes before EncryptCookies middleware, I am following the recommendation in the tutorial to manually encrypt the cookie:

```
if(!$request->hasCookie('referral')){

   return redirect($path)
   ->withCookie(cookie('referral', encrypt($name), 60*24*14));;

}
```

However, when this cookie is set as above for `$name = foo` and then retrieved using the cookie facade - the variable type and length is appended to the value:

```
dd(\Cookie::get('referral')) //Returns "s:3:"foo";"
```

From tracing back the cookie encryption built into laravel I think this probably has to do with serialization, but I can't seem to find the right option at setting or retrieving the cookie for the expected behavior:

```
dd(\Cookie::get('referral')) //Expected to return "foo"`
```

From testing in tinker and manually using `decrypt()` on the copy pasted cookie value, it is being *set* normally and the problem lies in the retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error in tinker, I worked out that in the EncryptCookies middleware there is a default value of `protected static $serialize = false;`.  This wasn't included in my encrypt() function.  The following code works as expected when retrieving the cookie:

```
if(!$request->hasCookie('referral')){

   return redirect($path)
   ->withCookie(cookie('referral', encrypt($name, false), 60*24*14));;

}
```